# Null values ​- Golang, libpq, postgresql

Tags: go, libpq

I have an application written in go, gin and libpq (postgresql)..
I'm working on a pretty big framework, and I'm crud on one of the tables in that framework..
my problem is in the GET method of the application, more specifically in a uuid field, which is not returning null values, it only returns an error, below is my code:

controllers:

```golang
func GetPrograma() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var GetAllPrograma []models.Programa

        rows, err := DB.Query(`SELECT * FROM sis_programa`)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao realizar select na tabela sis_programa ": err,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao realizar select na tabela sis_programa ", err)
            return
        }
        defer rows.Close()

        for rows.Next() {
            var getAll models.Programa
            var IDDashboard sql.NullString // Declaração da variável

            err := rows.Scan(&getAll.IDPrograma, &getAll.Denominacao, &getAll.Descricao, &getAll.TipoPrograma, &getAll.IDTabela, &getAll.FormularioNavegacao, &getAll.FormularioEdicao, &getAll.LinkAjuda, &IDDashboard, &getAll.RotaBackend, &getAll.Customizado, &getAll.DataInclusao, &getAll.IDUsuarioInclusao, &getAll.DataAlteracao, &getAll.IDUsuarioAlteracao)

            if IDDashboard.Valid {
                getAll.IDDashboard, _ = uuid.FromString(IDDashboard.String)
            }

            if err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa ": err,
                })
                log.Println("Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa ", err.Error())
                return
            }

            GetAllPrograma = append(GetAllPrograma, getAll)
        }

        if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao ler as linhas da tabela sis_programa ": err,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao ler as linhas da tabela sis_programa ", err.Error())
            return
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, GetAllPrograma)
    }
}
```

models:

```golang
package models

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/gofrs/uuid"
)

type Programa struct {
    IDPrograma          uuid.UUID `json:"id_programa"`
    Denominacao         string    `json:"denominacao"`
    Descricao           string    `json:"descricao"`
    TipoPrograma        int       `json:"tipo_programa"`
    IDTabela            uuid.UUID `json:"id_tabela"`
    FormularioNavegacao string    `json:"formulario_navegacao"`
    FormularioEdicao    string    `json:"formulario_edicao"`
    LinkAjuda           string    `json:"link_ajuda"`
    IDDashboard         uuid.UUID `json:"id_dashboard"`
    RotaBackend         string    `json:"rota_backend"`
    Customizado         bool      `json:"customizado"`
    DataInclusao        time.Time `json:"data_inclusao"`
    IDUsuarioInclusao   int64     `json:"id_usuario_inclusao"`
    DataAlteracao       time.Time `json:"data_alteracao"`
    IDUsuarioAlteracao  int64     `json:"id_usuario_alteracao"`
}
```

when performing get, I get this error in my console:

> Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa  sql: Scan error on column index 7, name "id_dashboard": converting NULL to string is unsupported

tentei usar uma consulta sql com COALESCE, mas nao obtive resultado, apenas erros

tentativa com COALESCE:

```golang
func GetPrograma() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var GetAllPrograma []models.Programa

        rows, err := DB.Query(`SELECT *,COALESCE(id_dashboard::text, '') AS id_dashboard  FROM sis_programa`)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao realizar select na tabela sis_programa ": err,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao realizar select na tabela sis_programa ", err)
            return
        }
        defer rows.Close()

        for rows.Next() {
            var getAll models.Programa
            var IDDashboard sql.NullString // Declaração da variável

            err := rows.Scan(&getAll.IDPrograma, &getAll.Denominacao, &getAll.Descricao, &getAll.TipoPrograma, &getAll.IDTabela, &getAll.FormularioNavegacao, &getAll.FormularioEdicao, &getAll.LinkAjuda, &IDDashboard, &getAll.RotaBackend, &getAll.Customizado, &getAll.DataInclusao, &getAll.IDUsuarioInclusao, &getAll.DataAlteracao, &getAll.IDUsuarioAlteracao)
            if IDDashboard.Valid {
                getAll.IDDashboard, _ = uuid.FromString(IDDashboard.String)
            }
            if err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa ": err,
                })
                log.Println("Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa ", err.Error())
                return
            }

            GetAllPrograma = append(GetAllPrograma, getAll)
        }

        if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "Erro ao ler as linhas da tabela sis_programa ": err,
            })
            log.Println("Erro ao ler as linhas da tabela sis_programa ", err.Error())
            return
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, GetAllPrograma)
    }
}
```

ERROR:

> Erro ao realizar scan na tabela sis_programa  sql: expected 16 destination arguments in Scan, not 15

Comment: Try using `*uuid.UUID`, or `uuid.NullUUID`. If that doesn't work you can declare a custom type that embeds `uuid.UUID` and that knows how to handle `NULL` from the DB by properly implementing the `sql.Scanner` interface. Alternatively do what you were doing with `COALESCE` but list all the columns and remove the wildcard `*` (it is the wildcard `*` plus the one COALESCE that cause the second error: "expected 16 but got 15")

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lomsa-dev/gonull

example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lomsa-dev/gonull"
)

type MyCustomInt int
type MyCustomFloat32 float32

type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Age     gonull.Nullable[MyCustomInt]
    Address gonull.Nullable[string]
    Height  gonull.Nullable[MyCustomFloat32]
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"Name":"Alice","Age":15,"Address":null,"Height":null}`)

    var person Person
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled Person: %+v\n", person)

    marshalledData, err := json.Marshal(person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled JSON: %s\n", string(marshalledData))
}
```